# Cant tell if phpactiverecord is connecting to database

Tags: phpactiverecord

I am writing a web service for a droid app adn trying to use phpactiverecord.  I am not using an mvc.  I cannot tell whether it is connecting to my database correctly because I don't know what it returns when it fails or if it just can't be used without an mvc.

```
   <?php 

require_once '../libs/php-activerecord/ActiveRecord.php';

 ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(function($cfg)
 {
     $cfg->set_model_directory('../libs/php-activerecord/models');
     $cfg->set_connections(array(
         'development' => 'mysql://username:password@localhost/dbname'));
 });

//$json=$_GET ['json'];
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);

//echo $json;

$data = Users::all();
$user_name = $data->user_name;
echo($data);
$password = $data->password;

  $posts = array(name =>$user_name,
                password =>$password
                );
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts));

?>
```

It throws a 500 error when I try to go to the page which isn't very helpful.

Comment: If 'it' throws a 500 error it means your code does ;). Read your error log, or set the display errors to true. Also set the error level higher. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Comment: There is at least one issue that doesn't have anything to do with the database: you do an echo (which forces a header to be sent) and then you send a second header. You can't do that ;)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out but thanks for trying to help.  My hosting server has a wierd structure that required my path to include a bunch of extra stuff that would be unlikely to happen to anyone else... basically my include pat was wrong. turning on error reporting pointed out the problem quickly.